# Al dar clic en un botón de mi página web, no cambia la imagen

Tags: javascript, html

En mi página web tengo este código:

```
<script>
     function encender(sw)
     {
        usar pic;
        if (sw==0) 
            pic="focoa.jpg";
        else
            pic="focoe.jpg";
        document.getElementsById('myImage').src=pic;
     }

</script>

    <img id='myImage' src="focoa.jpg" width="100" height="180">

    <p>
        <button type="button" onclick="encender(1)">Encender</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="encender(0)">Apagar</button>
    </p>
```

Sucede que al dar clic al botón no cambia la imagen y debería cambiar.

¿Cómo hacer para que la imagen cambie?

Comment: No existe la declaración   `usar pic` en JavaScript , `var pic` es lo más cercano a lo que busca. Y tampoco existe `getElementsById` , debe ser en singular , `getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la unica solucion que se me ocurrio espero que te sirva :D

```
<script>
    function cambiar() {
        document.getElementById('matrix').src = "focoa.jpg";
    }

    function volver() {
        document.getElementById('matrix').src = "focoe.jpg";
    }
</script>
<img id='matrix' src="2.jpg" width="100" height="180">
<p>
    <button type="button" onclick="cambiar()">Encender</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="volver()">Apagar</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios problemas de sintaxias en tu codigo. Una solucion puede ser esta:

```
    <script>

        function encender(sw) {

            var pic; 

            if (sw === 0) {
                pic = 'apagada.jpg';
            } else {
                pic = 'encendida.jpg';
            }

            document.getElementById('myImage').src = pic;
        }

    </script>

    <img id='myImage' src='apagada.jpg' width="100" height="180">

    <p>
        <button type="button" onclick="encender(1)">Encender</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="encender(0)">Apagar</button>
    </p>
```